# How can I create an AI for an android app which takes a user provided price offer & will either accept/reject/provide counter-offer as output?

Tags: android, artificial-intelligence

I firstly apologize in advance if my question is not concise & clear but I need dire help of your knowledge on Android app & AI. Our college group was given a Project topic: Bargaining on an price offer against an AI using Android App.

So basically create an App where we as user can give an offer of *'x' amount of object for 'y' amount of price*, & the AI should tackle our given offer by either rejecting & giving a completely new offer **generated by the AI** say 'x' amount of objects for 'z' amount of price OR accept the original offer, if it fits a certain criteria of 'not below *profitable* price range' for 'x' amount of objects.

I'm making this clear before hand that I'm not asking for a complete source code for the app at all! **Just guide me in the right direction** of how should I start making the app for this project from ground up along with an AI that can Bargain for a price offer against the user. Here are certain criteria that our project teacher gave us in regards for how the AI should be like:

- AI should not be just a yes or no machine, but also should be interactable with the user, like a Virtual Assistant. (So I'm guessing some of kind NLP needs to be involved, like a chatbot talks to user.)
- User cannot type an offer. It should be Auto-generated by the app as user selects the items & their bidding price using a selection menu and proceeding checkout. Offer is auto-generated & given to AI if user completes checkout.
- AI should not get stuck in an Infinite loop of counter-offers between it & user. (So I'm guessing if the AI did provide a counter-offer, & the user cannot get terms to it, then after 2 or 3 counter-offers, it should just terminate counter-offers, & ask for a completely new offer from the user, I suppose)
- If a counter-offer is placed by the AI, the user can only reply to the counter-offer by ACCEPT/REJECT response.
- If offer provided by user is completely unjustifiable (like ridiculously low price) then AI should just reject the offer completely *without* providing a counter offer.
- AI should *learn* from the list of previously accepted offers by user & update the 'most likely to be accepted' criteria range used during generation of counter-offer by the AI but also validate it against 'not below profitable price range' of criteria. (So I'm guessing this definitely involves Machine learning or AI learning, sigh)

Fellow Developers, I know this all looks a bit too intimidating as it looks to my group as well, but once again I'm not asking you to give me a source code. Just tell us how can we start building this project & train the AI to improve it's counter-offering techniques by learning from previously accepted offers, at the same time making it somewhat interactable with the user as well using Natural Language Processing to some extent.

Myself & a few of my group members have intermediate knowledge of app development & database management but none of us don't have a single clue about anything related AI development & training. So any help, courses, tutorial videos to help us will be much appreciated. Thank You, Developers.

Answer (score 3):

I was in a similar situation once regarding AI, my solution was to use a paid library rather than making my own(which is very time-consuming), the one I used was https://acquire.io/chatbot/ you can customize as per your needs, better you have a chat with the sales team and speak about your requirements.

I hope my answer is useful to you.